# Add line-Height Property to all <ul> through SQL query

Tags: sql, replace, tags, double-quotes

I need to add the line-height property to over 100+ ul list. I am using Big faceless, for some reason, I can't use the ul li selector to add this property through a stylesheet.

What I am trying to do now is to add line-height to all ul tags in sql but I keep getting "incorrect syntax near '+11+11'"  the following is my sql query:

```
update CO_DOC_TMPL_SECT
set SECTION_TEXT = replace(SECTION_TEXT, '<ul','<ul line-height='"'+11+'"'')
```

Can someone point out where I might have gone wrong? This is SQL 2008R2

Answer (score 0):

`'` Is used to denote strings amongst other **reserved** items in MySQL .. You should be escaping them.  IE `\'`  Or   `\'"\'+11+\''"\'`

**UPDATE**

```
UPDATE
  CO_DOC_TMPL_SECT
SET
  SECTION_TEXT = REPLACE(
    SECTION_TEXT,
    '<ul',
    '<ul line-height=\'"\'+11+\'"\''
  )
```

Comment: Hi Zak, thank you for helping out. Unfortunately, I still get a similar syntax error.

Comment: I've updated my answer .. I misplaced a escape character.